# 98 Subaru Forester starter motor replacement part compatibility

Tags: subaru, forester

my Forester's starter motor needs replacing. 
Can I replace the old one: 
23
23300 AA380
NO. 8120
Type MOOOT81681

with this one:
24
23300 AA390
NO. 8424
Type MOO1T84481

The replacement starter is from an automatic whereas my car is a manual, but the parts guy I bought the replacement from said that was fine. He said not to replace a 25 starter with the 24, but he didn't say anything about a 23 which mine has turned out to be.

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current 23 23300-AA380 is for a Manual transmission - 8 teeth. The replacement 24 23300-AA390 starter is for an Automatic transmission - 9 teeth.

The starter for the manual transmission has 8 teeth, while the starter for the Automatic transmission has 9 teeth (there are some electrical differences also - the automatic starter is 1.4Kw, the manual is 1Kw). It just won't work.

You can use the starter from any *Manual transmission* Forester, Impreza or Impreza Outback from  1998 - 2002.